# Cで文字列の比較を自作関数で行った際に問題が起こります

Tags: c

[AtCoder Beginners Contest (ABC) 241-B](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc247/tasks/abc247_b) を解くための問題をCで書きました。

問題は「それぞれ2個の文字列からなるn組の文字列の組が与えられる。各組の第一要素と第二要素のいずれか一方のみを選ぶとき選ばれた全てが、他の各組の第1または第2要素と一致しないようにすることができるか。」というものです。

下記のコードでACにはなったのですが、scmp1関数の中の if(i>=n) の所をコメントアウトなしにすると、例えば次の例(02_except_one_00)で、

```
100
avmlajlxrf zttmjemxex
vauvmzqhzs uzgvclqnem
lcljwpbfsg xnbsoouwsn
zifcqxivtq gjcupzgkyz
cinpwuotzy yxojlpipjn
tdnemryudq skxibydrct
tdjdtgtipl eurwjwxvyv
abzttwzxhb amycbijxta
vwzjmmlaew yxojlpipjn
xteucdfimo syiwqxsyvy
vowbgfxsqv sjcegwybmg
urdgjzthal cckapzefmh
jlqemwztfg yzlusdaezt
ejwwcutzsa atxkasugou
fvvvsecqvg csloaexqar
xdudibkgmt dmzuyjjkfu
jnmfxnucto anlkpmegdk
hlwnwahibo wdwgecsbqe
xoeqypczez txgzzkdeco
vrwhijewvl wytsxzogzb
flocshjexi vrounuangs
giiikhuvlw eapudjjlxz
asvwjrhpck oyyrexwiri
cqsqohapin ddpdojipiq
hgtmfsuedp tkjqmgetkl
emrjmdsahn urmlzavbyc
odultqflzd obnwbmbrbv
jhfxadevqt cinpwuotzy
dyvarcvxms tduoqcljzw
pcumzuyzgs xbfsoxvtlx
slzgvyptkq begswrioai
sikliwzvqd ivkzfnjnqs
fxfomljyeo rohrqgsbrr
mwtptktucb gabwlmmezw
swydbovjqx ybfbjxmlkw
qhpbuccyhu dsaxxwfler
guqxzzgrlr ftimlzorzv
bqklofbwzb pyemgoqbqp
xnzsfrgfqd fctpafbged
safprjkxav iducfibsms
bgaczxkjjo qdubpubmqy
gjfgwuapdu mxngjzuyzs
gfmrbrczyv wkybysnbzh
cpqnmbijhc tisbxwevsl
yyepttinlp qxdlcyaryl
rtfvtlsaed gxnmgfdlaz
cztjbttosy xvgevjycvc
niqyddonks pcntudhjex
eprhqytehu gxoechnwzq
uewhzvtawt hdkzmpoxdd
qrtpqcgzid jmdnedpvde
cbobbqkhvo fecwfsshrs
lxlwxjdune nbfsjuwwfl
nfolbzlgjz ayiiidkxpv
secemmlcyo binjogcrin
evzuvmvvxi wsxrlspmwe
edufzrlfzz uhzqiupfoc
cjehxnsfew lfxcujwugl
vfvxpvhkzp zwhyamzuqc
bmhndupair jmijqprnqv
rrxvdkpxxe comgvwojrd
shhltqafiy axpqnlimij
qwjlqpuqyr rwrkgculnr
isiadtwyew gmgrjchxeq
asydjlrgnu rsqxsdaeke
byeogugzvd oimjblsaqp
etfzxishqr zicggawrny
vrkvpixskp pootisasgb
jyquzkympl kpgrarjurw
irokbsgmzn axnmijtbuo
jcicrhohws glmxshpofv
mlcltqliqd edgalwqyrz
qabdaqkuvk gpwzxamavm
rjuybctves qoltuirrbt
ceehfrnnlt wzqpfbegeb
bygsepvzvs wivbkxcwwr
bztgqkaszz kbddlinrdl
bgcwkfhjfd anvaxdphvm
hmkrfrrykj tposlkgyfu
cvpzdchrcf jrkecgpdod
ziyqvltwjr jjywyobhow
mspuosmxsw plkwluwjpg
lnxxowqjmu eggxviqrxd
dgwlamwtdf svrlcuukan
edrefbtrce khqwssekyx
uhcvrasuxf vtvrbfeswq
jupyipafzd ufewjurxbj
bltjuxbtkv zmfhstxyzx
zgcxjwddcs xafyqtugis
glbrpmckrt xqxemkieyn
epbfldpccl idkkwdfvrc
rlcsstqdlx rvdzydkjnp
rhknmgmqdq xyumddhczm
ignokmfecc tizaaxfkgh
zlinrzhweq zzdpcqbjvc
emehoqjlcq gmvctsblgw
yargqiezlu oyifpuekox
ntveljeitx coyexswfvj
nbejnmvkdn amgirkcihn
lxlaawoatn qjofmdhvwt
```

実行結果が、

```
s=yxojlpipjn, t=yxojlpipjn, i=10
Comparing failed.
s=cinpwuotzy, t=cinpwuotzy, i=10
Comparing failed.
No
```

となります。(Paiza.ioでの実行結果)

この、文字数の上限+1番目のループは、必ずここに行く前に一番目 `(*(s+i)==0 && *(t+i)==0)` または二番目 `(*(t+i)!=*(s+i))` の条件が満たされて、ここに来ることはないはずなのですが、こうなってしまうのはなぜでしょうか。

ちなみに、同じ関数で、

```
char str1[4]="abc";
char str2[4]="abc";
scmp1(str1,str2,4);
```

としてみると、この現象は起きないようです。

```
typedef struct nom {
    char first[11];
    char last[11];
}nom;
int scmp1(char* s, char* t, int n);
int readint(char *s);
#define N1 5
#define N2 23
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    char* s1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N1);
    if(s1==NULL){
        printf("memory allocation to s1 failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fgets(s1,N1,stdin);
    int n=readint(s1);
    nom* nms=(nom*)malloc(sizeof(nom)*n); 
    if(nms==NULL){
        printf("memory allocation to nms failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        char* s2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N2);
        if(s2==NULL){
            printf("memory allocation to s2(%d) failed\n",j);
            exit(1);
        }    
        fgets(s2,N2,stdin);
        int k=0,l=0;
        while(*(s2+k)!=32){
            (nms+j)->first[k]=*(s2+k);
            k++;
        }
        (nms+j)->first[k]=0;
        k++;
        while(*(s2+k)>=97 && *(s2+k)<=122){
            (nms+j)->last[l]=*(s2+k);
            k++;l++;
        }
        (nms+j)->last[l]=0;
    }
/*
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("---nms(%d)---\n",j);
        printf("%s\n",(nms+j)->first);
        printf("%s\n",(nms+j)->last);
    }
*/
    int flag_first=1,flag_last=1;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        for(int h=0;h<n;h++){
            if(h==j)continue;
            if(scmp1((nms+j)->first,(nms+h)->first,10)==0){
                flag_first=0;
            }
            if(scmp1((nms+j)->first,(nms+h)->last,10)==0){
                flag_first=0;
            }
            if((scmp1((nms+j)->last,(nms+h)->first,10)==0)){
                flag_last=0;
            }
            if((scmp1((nms+j)->last,(nms+h)->last,10)==0)){
                flag_last=0;
            }
        }
        if(flag_first==0 && flag_last==0){
            printf("No\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    printf("Yes\n");
    return 0;
}
int readint(char *s){
    int i=0,ret=0;
    while(*(s+i)>=48 && *(s+i)<=57){
        ret*=10;
        ret+=*(s+i)-48;
        i+=1;
    }
    return ret;
}
int scmp1(char* s, char* t, int n){
    int i=0;
    while(1){
        if (*(s+i)==0 && *(t+i)==0) return 0;
        else if (*(t+i)!=*(s+i)) return (*(t+i)-*(s+i));
        else i++;
        if(i>=n){
//            printf("s=%s, t=%s, i=%d\n",s,t,i);
//            printf("Comparing failed.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 実行結果が、
>
> ```
> s=yxojlpipjn, t=yxojlpipjn, i=10
> Comparing failed.
> s=cinpwuotzy, t=cinpwuotzy, i=10
> Comparing failed.
> No
> ```
>
> となります。(Paiza.ioでの実行結果)
>
> この、文字数の上限+1番目のループは、必ずここに行く前に一番目`((s+i)==0 && (t+i)==0)`または`二番目((t+i)!=(s+i))`の条件が満たされて、ここに来ることはないはずなのですが、こうなってしまうのはなぜでしょうか。

`(i>=n)`の条件を満たして、コメントアウト部分が実行されるのは、(n+1)番目のループではなく、n番目のループになります。そこを勘違いされているのではないでしょうか。

`s="yxojlpipjn"`と`t="yxojlpipjn"`を`scmp1`で比較する場合を考えてみましょう。

| i | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s | 'y' | 'x' | 'o' | 'j' | 'l' | 'p' | 'i' | 'p' | 'j' | 'n' | '\0' |
| t | 'y' | 'x' | 'o' | 'j' | 'l' | 'p' | 'i' | 'p' | 'j' | 'n' | '\0' |

`i`が0～9の間は、`(*(s+i)==0 && *(t+i)==0)`も`(*(t+i)!=*(s+i))`も偽なので、`i++`が実行されます。`i`が9の時(=10回目のループ)に`i++`が実行されれば、`i`は10となり、`(i>=n)`の条件を満たしてコメントアウト部分が実行されることになります。

> ちなみに、同じ関数で、
>
> ```c
> char str1[4]="abc";
> char str2[4]="abc";
> scmp1(str1,str2,4);
> ```
>
> としてみると、この現象は起きないようです。

こちらは、`scmp1`の最後の引数に「文字列の長さ+1」の値を渡しているので、`(i>=n)`の条件が満たされるのは「文字数の長さ+1番目のループ」となります。
文字列`"yxojlpipjn"`の長さは10なので、この例と同じことをしたければ、`scmp1`の最後の引数に11を渡さなければなりません。